# Updating a dataframe based on another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have a DataFrame , say df1, which has all the columns correct except the 'Employee' column. There is another DataFrame , say df2, which has correct Employee names but stored in the column 'Staff'. I am trying to update df1 based on 'key_df1' and 'key_df2' from the respective DataFrames. Need some help on how to approach this question. (Please see below the expected output in the image)

```
data1=[['NYC-URBAN','JON','$5000','yes','BANKING','AC32456'],['WDC-RURAL','XING','$4500','Yes','FINANCE','AD45678'],['LONDON-URBAN','EDWARDS','$3500','No','IT','DE43216'],
     ['SINGAPORE-URBAN','WOLF','$5000','No','SPORTS','RT45327'],['MUMBAI-RURAL','NEMBIAR','$2500','No','IT','Rs454457']]

data2=[['NYC','MIKE','BANKING','BIKING','AH56245'],['WDC','ALPHA','FINANCE','TREKKING','AD45678'],
     ['LONDON-URBAN','BETA','FINANCE','SLEEPING','DE43216'],['SINGAPORE','WOLF','SPORTS','DANCING','RT45307'],
     ['MUMBAI','NEMBIAR','IT','ZUDO','RS454453']]

List1=['City','Employee', 'Income','Travelling','Industry', 'Key_df1']
List2=['City','Staff','Industry','Hobby', 'Key_df1']

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=List1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=List2)
```

Expected Ouput:

[image]

Edit (Additional Query):

Thanks for the response. Along with the above question, I want to concatenate value of 'Employee' column with the 'Travelling' Column from df1 only for the rows in which the Key_df1 and Key_df2 ties in the two DataFrames. Please see below the second expected output.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First set the index in *df1* to *Key_df1* and save it as a temporary DataFrame:

```
wrk = df1.set_index('Key_df1')
```

Then update (in-place) its *Employee* column using *df2* with the index
set to *Key_df2*, taking only *Staff* column:

```
wrk.Employee.update(df2.set_index('Key_df2').Staff)
```

And the last operation is to change the index to a "regular" column
and move it to the previous location:

```
result = wrk.reset_index().reindex(columns=List1)
```

The result is:

```
              City Employee Income Travelling Industry   Key_df1
0        NYC-URBAN      JON  $5000        yes  BANKING   AC32456
1        WDC-RURAL    ALPHA  $4500        Yes  FINANCE   AD45678
2     LONDON-URBAN     BETA  $3500         No       IT   DE43216
3  SINGAPORE-URBAN     WOLF  $5000         No   SPORTS   RT45327
4     MUMBAI-RURAL  NEMBIAR  $2500         No       IT  Rs454457
```

## Edit following the comment about *Travelling* column

Now just *update* is not enough and the task must be solved another way.

Start from joining *df1* with *df2.Staff* (with *set_index* to join properly):

```
result = df1.join(df2.set_index('Key_df2').Staff, on='Key_df1')
```

The second step (the actual update) is:

```
result.Employee.where(result.Staff.isna(), result.Staff + '_' + result.Travelling,
    inplace=True)
```

And the last step is to drop *Staff* column (not necessary any more):

```
result.drop(columns=['Staff'], inplace=True)
```

The final result is:

```
              City   Employee Income Travelling Industry   Key_df1
0        NYC-URBAN        JON  $5000        yes  BANKING   AC32456
1        WDC-RURAL  ALPHA_Yes  $4500        Yes  FINANCE   AD45678
2     LONDON-URBAN    BETA_No  $3500         No       IT   DE43216
3  SINGAPORE-URBAN       WOLF  $5000         No   SPORTS   RT45327
4     MUMBAI-RURAL    NEMBIAR  $2500         No       IT  Rs454457
```

Comment: Hi @Validi_Bo, thanks for the response. I am also trying to concatenate the updated 'Employee' column with 'Travelling' column. Could you pls help with this?

Comment: I have added expected output in the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Boolean Indexing, e.g.:

```
mask = df1.Key_df1 == df2.Key_df1.reindex(df1.index)
df1.loc[mask, 'Employee'] = df2.Staff
```

Output:

```
              City Employee Income Travelling Industry   Key_df1
0        NYC-URBAN      JON  $5000        yes  BANKING   AC32456
1        WDC-RURAL    ALPHA  $4500        Yes  FINANCE   AD45678
2     LONDON-URBAN     BETA  $3500         No       IT   DE43216
3  SINGAPORE-URBAN     WOLF  $5000         No   SPORTS   RT45327
4     MUMBAI-RURAL  NEMBIAR  $2500         No       IT  Rs454457
```

Comment: Hi your original answer with `df1.Employee[mask] = df2.Staff` seemed to work is there any reason you changed it to `df1.loc[mask, 'Employee'] = df2.Staff` ?

Comment: Nope, I just prefer it that way.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, first one was shorter, I liked it.

Comment: FWIW, you can do it in one line if you wish: `df1.loc[df1.Key_df1 == df2.Key_df1, 'Employee'] = df2.Staff`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @FelipeLanza In case df2 has different number of rows `df1.Employee[mask] = df2.Staff` this throws error. Is there a more generic approach because i had made up this a simple example. In real i have different rows in df2 than df1

Comment: Just re-index the smaller one with the index from the other. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy where:

```
import numpy as np

df1['Employee'] = np.where(df1['Key_df1'] == df2['Key_df1'], df2['Staff'], df1['Employee'])
```

Comment: True, just bear in mind that `isin` is not the same as an equality check.

Comment: @FelipeLanza You are right. It can work in this case, but it would be risky to use it for a big dataframe. I've edited my answer.